# Flash cursor remains arrow

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor

I've got an actionscript project (code I inherited) in which the cursor remains an arrow at all times. Even when I set a Sprite's buttonMode, nothing changes.

```
mySprite.buttonMode = true;
mySprite.useHandCursor = true;
mySprite.mouseChildren = false;
```

I've searched the project for terms like 'cursor' and the above 3, but I can't find anything.

Is there some global setting somewhere that disallows cursor modification? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is `mySprite` dispatching MouseEvents when you click or are all interactions disabled?

Comment: Are you on Firefox 4? There seems to be a bug there (at least on my Mac). I have the same problem but not on Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Does the parent of mySprite have mouseChildren set to false or any other mouse related settings ?

Comment: @JohnnyReeves -- Yes, dispatching MouseEvents.@prototypical -- no, I've checked for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySprite : Sprite = new Sprite;
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x99DD55);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(100,100,200,50);
mySprite.buttonMode = true;
mySprite.useHandCursor = true;
mySprite.mouseChildren = false;
```

This code works fine. Check you didn't set mouseChildren to false on a parent. You can check it by read back parent :

```
var c : DisplayObjectContainer = mySprite;
while(c)
{
    trace(getQualifiedClassName(c) + ", " + c.name + " : " + c.mouseChildren);
    c = c.parent;
}
```

Or may be you have a fullscreen sprite with alpha set to zero that catch all mouse Event.